# How to add a container on Page1 when button on Page2 is pressed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am badly stuck in a riddle since a couple of days. I know answer must be simple but still would appreciate your guidance.

**Problem:**
Let's say there are 2 pages, `page1` and `page2`. There is a `plusButton` in `page2` and what I want is, when this button is pressed, a container is added to `page1` lets say of width and height 100 and color blue.

Here is something, in my situation am also passing page one some parameters (two Strings) as well, so for clear understanding, mention that as well.

Comment: Please share your code for more clarification on what you are doing currently.

Answer (score 0):

With assumption that what you desire is to add a container to Page1 when a button on Page2 is pressed in Flutter, you can follow these steps:

Create the Page1 and Page2 widgets.
Pass data from Page2 to Page1 using constructor arguments.
Use a state management solution like Provider or Riverpod to trigger the addition of a container on Page1 from Page2.
Here's a simple example using Provider:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => ContainerData(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class ContainerData with ChangeNotifier {
  bool showContainer = false;
}



class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Page1(),
      routes: {
        '/page2': (context) => Page2(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final containerData = Provider.of<ContainerData>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 1'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            if (containerData.showContainer)
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final containerData = Provider.of<ContainerData>(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Page 2'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                containerData.showContainer = true;
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/page1');
              },
              child: Text('Add Container to Page 1'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```